# Objective C: OSStatus always returns 0. How to figure out if user has changed the default application or keep the older one

Tags: objective-c

I am asking a user to change its default browser to my application. In order to do it, I am using the following code.

`OSStatus httpResult = LSSetDefaultHandlerForURLScheme(CFSTR("https"), bundleID);`

The problem is above code is that `httpResult` is always *0* that's why I am not able to find out it the user has switched to my web browser or keep using the older one.

Is there any workaround for this problem.

Many thanks strckoverflowers

Comment: Doesn't `0` mean it set the handler correctly?  It's not a function to determine what is handling the URL, but a function to set the handler.

Comment: @trojanfoe sir, so is there a way to find out if the user has switched to my browser out not

Comment: No idea.  Perhaps there is "get" version of that function?

Answer (score 0):

You want LSCopyDefaultHandlerForURLScheme(), to determine which application is currently handling that scheme.

Comment: I know about this function. The problem is bit different. Actually i am already using thing function. The problem is that i need site thank-you message as soon as he switch to my browser